# ¿como consigo descubrir si hay un minimo de 3 elementos iguales juntos en las columnas de una matriz mediante java?

Tags: java

estoy en mitad de un juego donde debo rotar los elementos de una fila en una matriz de izquierda a derecha para conseguir que al rotar en alguna columna haya 3 elementos juntos y poder sumarlos. de momento he conseguido rotar las filas:

//filas es el nº de filas q tiene la matriz, fila es la que quiero mover y rotaciones
//es el numero de columnas que quiero q avance el primer elemento de la fila
public static void rotarFila(int[][] matriz, int filas, int fila, int rotaciones) {
for (int x = 0; x < rotaciones; x++) {

```
        int aux = matriz[fila][filas-1];
        for (int i = matriz.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            matriz[fila][i] = matriz[fila][i - 1];
        }
        matriz[fila][0] = aux;
    }   
}
```

luego recorro la matriz por columnas pero no se comprobar si hay al menos 3 elementos juntos en alguna columna

Answer (score 1):

No sé dónde quieres guardar la suma de esos números, pero aquí tienes una opción, otra cosa podría ser volver a recorrer la matriz con otro ciclo for.

```
int suma;

int aux = matriz[fila][filas-1];
    for (int i = matriz.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {

//Verifica si el ultimo número es igual a los dos anteriores (ya serían tres), si lo es, entonces suma.
if (matriz[fila][i] == matriz[fila][i-1] && matriz[fila][i] == matriz[fila][i-2])
suma = matriz[fila][i] + matriz[fila][i-1] + matriz[fila][i-2]

        matriz[fila][i] = matriz[fila][i - 1];
    }
    matriz[fila][0] = aux;
```